# Wordpress Ajax load more post

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, alpine.js

I have a simple post that I am using alipine.js to help me load post using AJAX.

So far it is loading my pages and changing the category if I click a filter button, this is all expected and working.

However I have updated my code to show more when click "load more button", this is not showing and giving no error.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

**the problem**
If i click load more its getting more post but of the same type, not 10 new post.

I believe the code is very close to working. its loading my post on click, just the same as already loaded.

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
         <script>
    Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
        posts: "",
        limit: 6,
        total: null,
        category: null,
        post_type_js: post_id,
        showDefault: true,
        showFiltered: false,
        offset: 0,
        
        filterPosts(id) {
            this.showDefault = false;
            this.showFiltered = true;
            this.category = id;
            this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
            this.fetchPosts();
        },
        
         loadMore() {
            this.loadingMore = true;
            this.offset += 10;
            this.showFiltered = true;
            this.fetchPosts(true);
        },
    
        fetchPosts(append = false) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
            formData.append("limit", this.limit);
            formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
            formData.append("offset", this.offset); // <-- Add new data to the form
    
            if (this.category) {
                formData.append("category", this.category);
            }
    
        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
                if (append) {
                    // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                    this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
                } else {
                    // Resets the posts data with new data
                    this.posts = res.posts;
                }
    
                this.loading = false;
            });
        },
        
        getTotal() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
    
        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            this.total = res.total;
        });
    },
    
    init() {
        this.getTotal();
    }
    
    }));
    })
         </script>
         
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
    <section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?> <?php theme_section_attr_class('main-section js-posts') ?>>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="heading mx-0">
          <?php $before_title = get_sub_field('before_title');
          if ($before_title) : ?>
            <strong class="sub-title"><?php echo $before_title ?></strong>
          <?php endif ?>
          <?php $title = get_sub_field('title');
          if ($title) : ?>
            <h2><?php echo $title ?> </h2>
          <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    
          <div class="head js-posts-search-text">
            <?php if ($search_value) : ?>
              <h2 class="h5 fw-semibold"><?php printf(__('Showing results for “%s”', 'base'), $search_value) ?></h2>
            <?php endif ?>
          </div>
          
    <!--alipne js dynamic post start-->
        <div class="has-filter row flex-md-row-reverse">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 js-posts-holder">
                
            <!-- Posts Column -->
                <div x-show.important="showDefault" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                    <!-- Default posts query -->
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/default-query' ); ?>
                </div>
                    <!-- Filtered posts -->
                <div x-show.important="showFiltered" x-html="posts"class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                </div>
                <!-- Load More Posts -->
                
           <!-- Load More Posts -->
    <div @click="loadMore()"  class="text-center mt-12 pt-5">
        <button class="">
            Load More
        </button>
    </div>
             </div>
                
            <!-- Filtered posts -->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                 <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/filter-query' ); ?>
            <!-- Filtered end -->
             </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
    <!--alipne js dynamic post end-->
    
    </section>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    // the ajax function
    add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
    
    function filterPosts()
    {
        $response = [
            'posts' => "",
        ];
            // New args for an All Posts Query
        $all_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // returns all posts
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
    
        
        $filter_args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
    
        if ($_POST['limit']) {
            $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
        }
        
         if ($_POST['post_type_js']) {
            $filter_args['post_type'] = $_POST['post_type_js'];
        }
    
        if ($_POST['category']) {
            $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
            
            // Get the total number of posts for the category
            $all_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
    
        }
    
        $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);
        
        // New All Posts Query
        $all_query = new WP_Query($all_args);
    
        
    
        if ($filter_query->have_posts()):
            while ($filter_query->have_posts()): 
                $filter_query->the_post();
                $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
    
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }
    
    
    function load_template_part($template_name, $part_name = null, $args = [])
    {
        ob_start();
        get_template_part($template_name, $part_name, $args);
        $var = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $var;
    }
```

Comment: It's not working is not enough for us to go on. Please specify where it goes wrong. Is the fetch being triggered? Are you getting a good request? Are you getting the payload you expected?

Comment: good point, will elaborate now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the 'offset' parameter, add it to *$filter_args*:

```
$filter_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

if (isset($_POST['offset'])) {                       // <<<< THIS
    $filter_args['offset'] = max (0, (int)$_POST['offset']);
}

if ($_POST['limit']) {
    $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
}

// .....
```

I also suggest you add a minimum of validation for the *$_POST* parameters like I did